# Does OpenThread have NXP KW2x support?

Tags: openthread

The [OpenThread press release](https://nest.com/press/nest-announces-open-source-implementation-of-thread/)

has verbage that says "OpenThread can run on Thread-capable radios and corresponding development kits from silicon providers like NXP Semiconductors and Silicon Labs."

Is this the current source and I just need to compile and start, or is this "it could have" support for NXP KW2x hardware if someone implemented a hardware abstraction layer for it?

If the latter, is there some docs or class that would be a starting point on how to add that to OpenThread?

Answer (score 0):

The latter. You need to implement functionality as specified in the [platform](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/include/platform) API headers (x). You can find example code for posix and cc2538 platforms [here](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples).